# RecyclerView no adapter attached; skipping layout error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

A similar question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout), but none of the solutions helped in my case.

I'm trying to get movie reviews data using Retrofit and then using it to populate my RecyclerView.

First I get a response which is then saved in my **MovieReviewsList**

Code for MovieReviewsList:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieReviewsList {
    @SerializedName("results")
    private final List<MovieReview> movieReviewsList;


    public MovieReviewsList(List<MovieReview> movieReviewsList) {
        this.movieReviewsList = movieReviewsList;
    }

    public List<MovieReview> getMovieReviewsList() {
        return movieReviewsList;
    }

    public int size() {
        return movieReviewsList.size();
    }
}
```

This class just stores a List of MovieReviews.

Code for MovieReviews:

```
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class MovieReview {
        @SerializedName("author")
        private final String movieReviewAuthor;
        @SerializedName("url")
        private final String movieReviewUrl;


        public MovieReview(String movieReviewAuthor, String movieReviewUrl) {
            this.movieReviewAuthor = movieReviewAuthor;
            this.movieReviewUrl = movieReviewUrl;
        }

        public String getMovieReviewAuthor() {
            return movieReviewAuthor;
        }

        public String getMovieReviewUrl() {


     return movieReviewUrl;

}
```

Then I'm trying to display that data in my activity. But every time I run my app I get ***No adapter attached; skipping layout error***.

Here is my activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.popularmovies.R;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.databinding.ActivityDetailBinding;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.movies.Movie;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.movies.MovieReview;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.movies.MovieReviewsList;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.movies.MovieTrailersList;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.MoviesClient;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.NetworkUtils;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.RetrofitInstance;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "DetailActivity";

    private MovieTrailersAdapter movieTrailersAdapter;
    private MovieReviewsAdapter movieReviewsAdapter;

    private Disposable movieTrailersCall;
    private Disposable movieReviewsCall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Intent launchingIntent = getIntent();
        if (launchingIntent == null || !launchingIntent.hasExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_MOVIE)) {
            finish();
        }
        String movieAsJson = launchingIntent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_MOVIE);
        Movie movie = new Gson().fromJson(movieAsJson, Movie.class);

        // Trailers
        RecyclerView movieTrailersRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.trailers_rv);
        LinearLayoutManager trailersLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        movieTrailersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(trailersLinearLayoutManager);
        movieTrailersAdapter = new MovieTrailersAdapter();
        movieTrailersRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieTrailersAdapter);

        // Reviews
        RecyclerView movieReviewsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reviews_rv);
        LinearLayoutManager reviewsLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        movieReviewsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(reviewsLinearLayoutManager);
        movieReviewsAdapter = new MovieReviewsAdapter();
        movieReviewsRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieReviewsAdapter);

        // Network call
        getMovieTrailersAndReviews(movie);

        ActivityDetailBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_detail);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(NetworkUtils.getImageUrl(movie.getThumbnailPath()))
                .into(binding.thumbnailIv);
        binding.setMovie(movie);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void getMovieTrailersAndReviews(Movie movie) {
        if (movie == null || !NetworkUtils.isConnectedToInternet(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
        MoviesClient moviesClient = retrofit.create(MoviesClient.class);

        Call<MovieTrailersList> movieTrailersCall = moviesClient.getMovieTrailers(movie.getId(), NetworkUtils.API_KEY);
        movieTrailersCall.enqueue(new Callback<MovieTrailersList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieTrailersList> call, Response<MovieTrailersList> response) {
                movieTrailersAdapter.setData(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieTrailersList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        Call<MovieReviewsList> movieReviewsCall = moviesClient.getMovieReviews(movie.getId(), NetworkUtils.API_KEY);
        movieReviewsCall.enqueue(new Callback<MovieReviewsList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieReviewsList> call, Response<MovieReviewsList> response) {
                movieReviewsAdapter.setData(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieReviewsList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I have logged a bunch of times and I have made sure that my network call always returns data. Then I set that data, inside of my onResponse callbacks, in my adapter.

Here is the code for my adapter:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.popularmovies.R;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.movies.MovieReview;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.network.movies.MovieReviewsList;

public class MovieReviewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieReviewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "MovieReviewsAdapter";

    private MovieReviewsList reviewsList;

    public MovieReviewsAdapter() { }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View containerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.review_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(containerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MovieReview movieReview = reviewsList.getMovieReviewsList().get(position);
        holder.reviewedByTextView.setText(movieReview.getMovieReviewAuthor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (reviewsList == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return reviewsList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView reviewedByTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            reviewedByTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_by_tv);
        }
    }

    public void setData(MovieReviewsList movieReviewsList) {
        this.reviewsList = movieReviewsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Log errors:

```
02-21 10:21:31.708 17295-17295/com.example.android.popularmovies E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

I have read [this post which is on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout), but I haven't found a solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: If you mean that I am getting two **No adapter attached; skipping layout** log errors, you are correct. But that is since I am doing the same thing to get movie trailers. I didn't include that code since the implementation is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few day of debugging, I have found out that the problem is causing **data binding** inside of my layout. I don't know exactly what is wrong, but I can tell that when I remove data binding and use Butter Knife to populate my views, I no longer get any log errors and my activity works as expected.

Here is my layout with data binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="movie"
            type="com.example.android.popularmovies.network.movies.Movie" />
    </data>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.example.android.popularmovies.ui.DetailActivity">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail_of_the_image"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/mad_max" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_title_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{movie.title}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
                tools:text="Mad Max - Fury Road" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/release_date_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@{movie.releaseDate}"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/released_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/released_label"
                tools:text="May 14, 2015" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@{movie.userRating}"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/rating_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rating_label"
                tools:text="8/10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rating"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/released_label"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/released_label" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/released_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/released"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/movie_title_tv"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_title_tv" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@{movie.plotSynopsis}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
                tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description_tv" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trailers_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/trailers_label"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description_tv" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/trailers_rv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trailers_label" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reviews_label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/reviews_label"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trailers_rv" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/reviews_rv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reviews_label" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

My layout after removing data binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.example.android.popularmovies.ui.DetailActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail_of_the_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@drawable/mad_max" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_title_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
            tools:text="Mad Max - Fury Road" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/release_date_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/released_label"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/released_label"
            tools:text="May 14, 2015" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/rating_label"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rating_label"
            tools:text="8/10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rating"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/released_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/released_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/released_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/released"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/movie_title_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_title_tv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thumbnail_iv"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description_tv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trailers_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/trailers_label"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description_tv" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/trailers_rv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trailers_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reviews_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/reviews_label"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trailers_rv" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reviews_rv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reviews_label" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I still don't have a clear answer as to why this is happening, but at least the code works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
private RecyclerView movieReviewsRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView reviewReviewsRecyclerView;
```

Try declaring this paramaters as you have done for adapters and then call

```
movieReviewsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

on response from api call

Answer (score 0):

Do this in `onResponse()` of retrofit call

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieReviewsList> call, 
                               Response<MovieReviewsList> response) {

        movieReviewsAdapter.setData(response.body());

        }
```

> **and in your adapter(you should do)**

```
public void setData(MovieReviewsList movieReviewsList) {
    this.reviewsList = movieReviewsList.getMovieReviewsList() ;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> this is because you are initializing the Java **Collections.List** with **POJO OBJECT**
>
> **Update** :- You are doing this...instead of the above process...(what are you doing)

```
public void setData(MovieReviewsList movieReviewsList) {
    this.reviewsList = movieReviewsList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I have changed all of my adapters to use Lists instead of MovieReviewList. I have also updated setData method as you suggested, but unfortunately, I still haven't resolved my problem.

Comment: Yes, I did do that

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in adapter code.

```
  private static final String TAG = "MovieReviewsAdapter";

private List<MovieReview> reviewsList;

public MovieReviewsAdapter(List<MovieReview> movieReviewsList) {
    this.reviewsList=movieReviewsList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View containerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.review_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(containerView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MovieReview movieReview = reviewsList.get(position);
    holder.reviewedByTextView.setText(movieReview.getMovieReviewAuthor());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (reviewsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return reviewsList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    final TextView reviewedByTextView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        reviewedByTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_by_tv);
    }
}
```

then after when you getting api response that time put below code..

```
 movieReviewsAdapter = new MovieReviewsAdapter(response.body().getMovieReviewsList());
    movieReviewsRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieReviewsAdapter);
```